# Send RS report to every single email within SQL query

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Using SQL Services 2005. 
I have a report in Microsoft Visual Studio 2005: Projects.rdl

In the dataset I have the following query:
(Showing me the previous month, where projects are overdue)

```
SELECT [Date], [Project], [Project Owner], [Email]
FROM [Table1]
WHERE [Date] < (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())
```

Now I want to send a RS Report to each [Project Owner], without having to create a report for each user with their specific filter.

That is I want to avoid doing the following for every report sent to each user:

```
SELECT [Date], [Project], [Project Owner], [Email]
FROM [Table1]
WHERE [Date] < (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())
AND [Project Owner] = 'AceAlfred'
```

Does Data-Drive-Subscription provide this feature??

---

UPDATE:

```
SELECT [Date], [Project], [Project Owner], [Email]
FROM [Table1]
WHERE [Date] < (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())
AND [Email] = @email
```

Error message:
The report parameter ‘email’ has a DefaultValue or a ValidValue that depends on the report parameter “email”. Forward dependencies are not valid. (rsInvalidReportParameterDependency)

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is to send the project owner as a parameter.

On the menu of your report project go to `Report > ReportParameters` and add a new parameter called `@projectOwner`

Then your query will look like

```
SELECT [Date], [Project], [Project Owner], [Email]
FROM [Table1]
WHERE [Date] < (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())
AND [Project Owner] = @projectOwner
```

Comment: OK good point, now the report needs a filter that sends only the projects related to the project owner. Would that be:
AND @projectOwner in (SELECT distinct [Project Owner])
?

Comment: @AceAlfred The query above will only return the projects where the [Project Owner] is equal to the projectOwner parameter. I'm assuming that [Project Owner] is a string.